# Allow Program To Use More CPU

Tags: c#, cpu

I've a console application in C#. I've a heavy process in my app after running it takes to much time but CPU usage of program is 7%! How can i allow my app to use at least 80% of CPU usage ?

```
double num = a milion digit int

while (num != 0)
{
    sum += num % 10;
    num /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: There is no disallowal in CPU usage by default, you might want to rewrite your application.

Comment: Why would you want to use higher CPU usage?

Comment: You should check why your application 'takes too much time'. Maybe it's out of available memory? Maybe it's writing loads of data to your hard drive? We need more information and preferably code to be able to help you.

Comment: Try making it more efficient. Generally speaking, your application can usage as much CPU as it wants to.

Comment: I know why. its geting sum of a milion digits of an int

Comment: Can you add your code to your question?

Comment: What value is 'a million digit int' ?

Comment: something like this, but now how can i increase speed of calculation?

Comment: @Arian This computation is likely to be finished within such a short amount of time that you are almost certainly going to be better off changing nothing.  Anything that you'd change would almost certainly slow down the app, because it's just so fast as it is.  A `double` can only store a few hundred digits, so going through every single one will only take at most a few hundred iterations, which a computer can do in milliseconds.

Comment: You should first determine what is 'too long' in your case. Should your calculations be done in 10 seconds or 10 minutes? What do you consider acceptable? Also, what value does `num` have when it enters the while loop?

Comment: it takes more than 10seconds, my cpu info is Intel Core i7 , 8Cores , 3.3GHZ

Answer (score 1):

You're using just one core. You need to use parallel programming to make use of today's multicore CPUs. Read more about parallel programming here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Right, in principle, but if the one core stays at 7% then the bottleneck is somewhere else and more cores are likely to hit the same spot..

Answer (score 0):

Modern CPUs should be done with that particular calculation in no-time. Also, threads use as much CPU as they need and are assigned to by the OS, not as much CPU as they are assigned to by you (provided that you don't mess around with CPU affinity in the task manager or that you don't use other tricks). Assigning more CPU time to your process (if it can be done at all), will not benefit you.

Since you don't provide all information (What is the type of `sum`? What are you trying to do?), we can only guess what is happening. Does your program ever get out of that while loop? Will the value of `num` (repeatedly divided by 10) every be equal to zero? My guess is that `num` will never be zero, so your program will stay in that while loop.

Comment: dividing by 10 is for getting the digits. it must finish

Comment: When `num` has a value of `1234567`, it won't (at least not when you'd expect it to).